# Akka non blocking options when an HTTP response is requied

Tags: http, scala, akka, nonblocking

I understand how to make a message based non-blocking application in akka, and can easily mock up examples that perform
concurrent operations and pass back the aggregated results in a message. Where I have difficulty is understanding what my
non-blocking options are when my application has to respond to an HTTP request. The goal is to receive a request and
immediately hand it over to a local or remote actor to do the work, which in turn will hand it off to get a result that
could take some time. Unfortunatly under this model, I don't understand how I could express this with a non-blocking
series of "tells" rather than blocking "asks". If at any point in the chain I use a tell, I no longer have a future to
use as the eventual response content (required by the http framework interface which in this case is finagle - but that is not 
important). I understand the request is on its own thread, and my example is quite contrived, but just trying to 
understand my design options.

In summary, If my contrived example below can be reworked to block less I very much love to understand how. This is my 
first use of akka since some light exploration a year+ ago, and in every article, document, and talk I have viewed says 
not to block for services.

Conceptual answers may be helpful but may also be the same as what I have already read. Working/Editing my example
would likely be key to my understanding of the exact problem I am attempting to solve. If the current example is generally
what needs to be done that confirmation is helpful too, so I don't search for magic that does not exist.

Note The following aliases: import com.twitter.util.{Future => TwitterFuture, Await => TwitterAwait}

```
object Server {

  val system = ActorSystem("Example-System")

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(1 seconds)

  implicit def scalaFuture2twitterFuture[T](scFuture: Future[T]): TwitterFuture[T] = {
    val promise = TwitterPromise[T]
    scFuture onComplete {
      case Success(result)  ⇒ promise.setValue(result)
      case Failure(failure) ⇒ promise.setException(failure)
    }
    promise
  }

  val service = new Service[HttpRequest, HttpResponse] {
    def apply(req: HttpRequest): TwitterFuture[HttpResponse] = req.getUri match {
      case "/a/b/c" =>
        val w1 = system.actorOf(Props(new Worker1))

        val r = w1 ? "take work"

        val response: Future[HttpResponse] = r.mapTo[String].map { c =>
          val resp = new DefaultHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK)
          resp.setContent(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(c, CharsetUtil.UTF_8))
          resp
        }

        response
    }
  }

//val server = Http.serve(":8080", service); TwitterAwait.ready(server)

  class Worker1 extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    def receive = {
      case "take work" =>
        val w2 = context.actorOf(Props(new Worker2))
        pipe (w2 ? "do work") to sender
    }
  }

  class Worker2 extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    def receive = {
      case "do work" =>
        //Long operation...
        sender ! "The Work"
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val r = service.apply(
      com.twitter.finagle.http.Request("/a/b/c")
    )
    println(TwitterAwait.result(r).getContent.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8)) // prints The Work
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance offered!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid sending a future as a message by using the [pipe pattern](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#ask-send-and-receive-future)—i.e., in `Worker1` you'd write:

```
pipe(w2 ? "do work") to sender
```

Instead of:

```
sender ! (w2 ? "do work")
```

Now `r` will be a `Future[String]` instead of a `Future[Future[String]]`.

---

Update: the `pipe` solution above is a general way to avoid having your actor respond with a future. As Viktor points out in a comment below, in this case you can take your `Worker1` out of the loop entirely by telling `Worker2` to respond directly to the actor that it (`Worker1`) got the message from:

```
w2.tell("do work", sender)
```

This won't be an option if `Worker1` is responsible for operating on the response from `Worker2` in some way (by using `map` on `w2 ? "do work"`, combining multiple futures with `flatMap` or a `for`-comprehension, etc.), but if that's not necessary, this version is cleaner and more efficient.

---

That kills one `Await.result`. You can get rid of the other by writing something like the following:

```
val response: Future[HttpResponse] = r.mapTo[String].map { c =>
  val resp = new DefaultHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK)
  resp.setContent(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(c, CharsetUtil.UTF_8))
  resp
}
```

Now you just need to turn this `Future` into a `TwitterFuture`. I can't tell you off the top of my head exactly how to do this, but it should be [fairly trivial](https://gist.github.com/arschles/5504373), and definitely doesn't require blocking.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response Travis. That does clean up the futures and the awaits a bit. So do you believe the use of the two asks is in fact required (Obviously I could only see it that way - but wanted to make sure)? I will update my code to include your improvements and include the implicit conversions from an akka future to a twitter future. Not too familiar with Stack Overflow etiquette yet, so I am giving a +1 for improvement. Any additional information on the asks would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to say whether the asks are required without knowing more about what those actors are responsible for, but the important part is that asking doesn't require blocking (there's a little extra bookkeeping involved, but it's still asynchronous). I'd also suggest keeping the conversion between Twitter and standard library futures explicit—having to call a conversion method is usually a small price to pay to avoid potential confusion in a case like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and insight on this Travis. This solves my concerns perfectly.

Comment: As a sidenote: ``pipe(w2 ? "do work") to sender`` is isomorphic to ``w2.tell("do work", sender)`` but doesn't create an intermediate actor nor needs timeouts etc.

Comment: Thanks again for you help Travis and thanks for the additional confirmation Viktor.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't have to block at all here.  First, update your import for the twitter stuff to:

```
 import com.twitter.util.{Future => TwitterFuture, Await => TwitterAwait, Promise => TwitterPromise}
```

You will need the twitter `Promise` as that's the impl of `Future` you will return from the `apply` method.  Then, follow what Travis Brown said in his answer so your actor is responding in such a way that you do not have nested futures.  Once you do that, you should be able to change your `apply` method to something like this:

```
def apply(req: HttpRequest): TwitterFuture[HttpResponse] = req.getUri match {
  case "/a/b/c" =>
    val w1 = system.actorOf(Props(new Worker1))

    val r = (w1 ? "take work").mapTo[String]
    val prom = new TwitterPromise[HttpResponse]
    r.map(toResponse) onComplete{
      case Success(resp) => prom.setValue(resp)
      case Failure(ex) => prom.setException(ex)            
    }

    prom
}

def toResponse(c:String):HttpResponse = {
  val resp = new DefaultHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK)
  resp.setContent(ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(c, CharsetUtil.UTF_8))
  resp
}
```

This probably needs a little more work.  I didn't set it up in my IDE, so I can't guarantee you it compiles, but I believe the idea to be sound.  What you return from the `apply` method is a `TwitterFuture` that is not yet completed.  It will be completed when the future from the actor ask (?) is done and that's happing via a non-blocking `onComplete` callback.

Comment: I had updated my answer with the implicit and changes, refreshed and saw your answer which is essentially the same functionally just inline. Thanks for taking the time. I assume by both your answers the asks are in fact ok. It was mostly an exercise in killing the awaits by either your method or the method proposed by Travis which I believe are equivalent correct? Thanks again.

Comment: Rolling the future conversion up with the response building logic like this doesn't seem ideal to me—especially if the conversion is necessary elsewhere as well (which is likely). Is there a reason you'd suggest this approach over mapping on the future and then converting?

Comment: @TravisBrown, just for simplicity of the example, I will update in a sec showing a `map` first to convert before doing the `onComplete`.  This is what you were talking about right?